# EWS: copy items between mailboxes/accounts

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

If my app has the credentials of two users, user A and user B, whose accounts/mailboxes are on the same Exchange server, is there a way that I can copy an item (e.g. an email) from a folder in user A's mailbox to one in user B's, and keep the traffic local to the Exchange server?

Neither user would have delegated/granted access to the other, and I'd prefer not to have to do this via a public folder.

Comment: This looks like a strong candidate for the answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135142(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727009/ews-managed-api-how-to-copy-items-from-one-mailbox-to-other

Answer (score 2):

Exporting with the ExportItems operation and importing with the UploadItems operation are your best options. New content was just released on MSDN that discussed this in detail: [Exporting and importing items by using EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672316%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - not sure this meets the goal of keeping traffic local to the Exchange Server though?

Comment: Do you have the ability to run the app on the server?

Comment: Unfortunately not, hence my original question.

Comment: Ah, I see the conundrum. I asked around and we can't think of a way to make this work with EWS. PowerShell may be an option, I'd have to investigate, I don't know off the top of my head.