# EWS Managed API - How to copy items from one mailbox to other

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, exchange-server-2010, ews-managed-api

I am writing an application(C#) to sync contacts,appointments,tasks etc from one mailbox to other. I am able to retrieve changes to these items using SyncFolderItems but could not find a way to copy the changes to a different mailbox. It looks like I have to create a new item for each of these types on the destination mailbox. If that is the case how do I get all the properties on the source item onto the new item on the destination. I am currently using exchange 2007 sp1 environment and want to use the same code for exchange 2010 also.

Answer (score 2):

(This is what worked for me on Exchange 2010. The docs don't mention 2007 so you may be out of luck there.)

Use [`SyncFolderItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa563967%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) to find the items you want to move. Next, use [`ExportItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff709490%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx) to export them to a file, and then [`UploadItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff709490%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx) to put them into the other mailbox. [ExportItems and UploadItems operations with Exchange Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh135142%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) is very detailed and has examples of the import/export operation (including an example where the source and destination are different mailboxes).